# WCF service polling

Tags: wcf, polling, throttling

I want to create a WCF Rest service, which will be polled by other platform.
I want to limit the no of polls they make, so that my service doesn't hangup.
Also automatically reject the polls if they exceed their limit.
Is there a way in WCF to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The phrase you're looking for here is *[Rate limiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting)*. And there's no built-in way. You can play with the WCF feature set around [service throttling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735114%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but this is a service-level setting and not per-client.

In order to implement rate limiting the guidance seems to be to use an in-memory 
hashtable or cache to perform fast look-ups against the incoming IP address. Then you can define some algorithm around that information.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450217/what-is-the-best-way-to-implement-a-rate-limiting-algorithm-for-web-requests) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775079/how-to-rate-limit-an-api).